# MFC date time picker zero value

Tags: c++, mfc

Is it possible to set its value to 0 in time mode? I've tried

```
CTime time;
m_Time.setTime(&time);
```

, but it shows 1:0:0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, see the strTime below, its value is "0:0:0". However if you are looking for time interval and not for the actual time better use CTimeSpan, see below also.

```
   time_t date1_t, date2_t;
   tm date_tm;

   date_tm.tm_hour   =0;
   date_tm.tm_min   =0;
   date_tm.tm_mon   =0;
   date_tm.tm_sec   =0;
   date_tm.tm_wday   =0; //Day of week (0-6; Sunday = 0)
   date_tm.tm_yday =1;
   date_tm.tm_year   =97;
   date_tm.tm_isdst =-1; //Positive if Daylight Saving Time is in effect;
                         //0 if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect; 
                         //Negative if status of DST is unknown.

   date_tm.tm_mday   =0;
   date2_t = mktime(&date_tm);

   date_tm.tm_mday   =0;
   date_tm.tm_isdst =0;
   date1_t = mktime(&date_tm);

   CTime time1(date1_t), time2(date2_t);
   CTimeSpan ts = time2 - time1;
   CString strTime = time1.Format("%H:%M:%S");
```

Comment: Thanks, will take a look on CTimeSpan.